# Not to overwrite output file when using C# setup project

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# setup project, and one of the outputs is XML file.

I want the setup project to write that file only if it doesn't exist on the target folder.

I've searched all over and did not find how to do it.

Help ?

Comment: Get the existing data from the folder.Compare it with the new one.If find any changes alter it.

Comment: That is a deployment project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `msbuild` target tasks to do this. There are possibilities to ad condition on any build task. 
For example:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
   <ItemGroup>
       <Copy Condition="!Exist('$(DestinationFolder)\$(FileName)')" SourceFiles="$(ProjectFilePath)\$(FileName)" DestinationFolder="$(DestinationFolder)" />
   </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: @ohadinho Unload Project -> Edit -> At the very end of the project definitions -> Reload project;